# AppEngine.iml pom.xml both list dependencies, what goes in which?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea, android-studio

steps: New Project, Generate AppEngine

examine -AppEngine.iml and pom.xml in AppEngine module,

Following the https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api

I added these imports:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

this would not compile (javax.inject not found) so I modified d20-AppEngine.iml
which did not help:

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: javax.inject:javax.inject:1" level="project" />
```

so I added to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

and it compiles.

What is the happening with the .iml file and the pom.xml file?  When would I add Maven  information versus Gradle dependencies in pom.xml

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.iml` file is specific to Intellij. When describing dependencies you should only use the `pom.xml` or the equivalent of gradle.

The IDEA project files like `.iml` are generated off the `pom.xml`. This is a good thing because if you are working with another developer they can use an IDE of their choice. There is no special IDE properties they have to set.